# Fast algorithm for calculating second-order adacency matrix from first-order adjacency matrix with a probabilistic directed graph

Tags: r, algorithm, matrix, vectorization, adjacency-matrix

I'm working with adjacency matrices that look like this:

```
N <- 5
A <- matrix(round(runif(N^2),1),N)
diag(A) <- 0

1> A
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
[1,]  0.0  0.1  0.2  0.6  0.9
[2,]  0.8  0.0  0.4  0.7  0.5
[3,]  0.6  0.8  0.0  0.8  0.6
[4,]  0.8  0.1  0.1  0.0  0.3
[5,]  0.2  0.9  0.7  0.9  0.0
```

Probabilistic and directed.

Here is a slow way to calculate the probability that `i` is linked to `j` through at least one other node:

```
library(foreach)
`%ni%` <- Negate(`%in%`) #opposite of `in`
union.pr <- function(x){#Function to calculate the union of many probabilities
  if (length(x) == 1){return(x)}
  pr <- sum(x[1:2]) - prod(x[1:2])
  i <- 3
  while(i <= length(x)){
    pr <- sum(pr,x[i]) - prod(pr,x[i])
    i <- 1+i
  }
  pr
}

second_order_adjacency <- function(A, i, j){#function to calculate probability that i is linked to j through some other node
  pr <- foreach(k = (1:nrow(A))[1:nrow(A) %ni% c(i,j)], .combine = c) %do% {
    A[i,k]*A[k,j]
  }
  union.pr(pr) 
}
#loop through the indices...
A2 <- A * NA
for (i in 1:N){
for (j in 1:N){
  if (i!=j){
    A2[i,j] <- second_order_adjacency(A, i, j)
  }
}} 
diag(A2) <- 0 
1>   A2
         [,1]     [,2]     [,3]     [,4]     [,5]
[1,] 0.000000 0.849976 0.666112 0.851572 0.314480
[2,] 0.699040 0.000000 0.492220 0.805520 0.831888
[3,] 0.885952 0.602192 0.000000 0.870464 0.790240
[4,] 0.187088 0.382128 0.362944 0.000000 0.749960
[5,] 0.954528 0.607608 0.440896 0.856736 0.000000
```

This algorithm scales like N^2, and I've got thousands of nodes.  And my matrix isn't all that sparse -- a lot of small numbers with a few big ones.  I could parallelize it, but I'd only be dividing by the number of cores.  Is there some vectorized trick that allows me to take advantage of the relative speed of vectorized operations?

tl;dr: how can I quickly calculate a second-order adjacency matrix in a probablistic directed graph?

Comment: This gotta be scaled by N^2 due to the structure. I would replace your union.pr function by 1-prod(1-pr) and I believe that will improve your running speed by a lot.

Answer (score 1):

Your union.pr function is slower by 500 times than a simple and efficient way. So replace your union.pr by 1-prod(1-pr) and you'll get 500X speed.

```
x <- runif(1000)*0.01

t1 <- proc.time()
for (i in 1:10000){
  y <- union.pr(x)
}
t1 <- proc.time()-t1
print(t1)
# user  system elapsed 
# 21.09    0.02   21.18 

t2 <- proc.time()
for (i in 1:10000){
  y <- 1-prod(1-x)
}
t2 <- proc.time() - t2
print(t2)
# user  system elapsed 
# 0.04    0.00    0.03
```

Answer (score 0):

So @Julius's answer was useful for reminding me of some elementary probability rules, but it didn't speed up the rate of computation much.  The following function, however, helps a ton:

```
second_order_adjacency2 <- function(A, i, j){#function to calculate probability that i is linked to j through some other node
  a1 <- A[i,1:nrow(A) %ni% c(i,j)]
  a2 <- t(A)[j,1:nrow(A) %ni% c(i,j)]
  1-prod(1-a1*a2)
}
```

It still scales like N^2 because it is a loop, but takes advantage of vectorization in the calculation of the various paths from `i` to `j`.  As such it is much faster.